# Evaluate $\int \frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)\sqrt {1+x^4}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}{(x+\frac 1x)\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2} + x^2}}dx$$
Let $x+\frac 1x = t$
$$-\int \frac{dt}{t\sqrt {t^2-2}}$$

Let $\sqrt{t^2-2} =u$
$$-\int \frac{du}{t^2}$$
$$-\int \frac{du}{u^2+2}$$
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \arctan (\frac{u}{\sqrt 2})$$
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \arctan (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sqrt { x^2 +\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

But the given answer is$ \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} \arcsin (\frac{\sqrt {2 x}}{x^2+1})$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Two ways to know if the integral you found is the right one. 1) Derive your integral and simplify and compare to the integrand. 2) Subtract your integral from the given answer and simplify; you should get a constant. Both can more easily be done using a CAS, Wolfram Alpha for example. You could also graph both integrals and observe if the graphs are always "parallel", that is if they differ by a constant, but beware that you should graph on the whole of the real line to be assured of your answer.

Comment: @KentaS how would I obtain the required answer directly?

Comment: @KentaS Are you sure they are the same? To me it seems like his final answer is same as $-\frac {1}{\sqrt 2} \arccos (\frac{\sqrt {2 x}}{x^2+1})$ and not arcsin.

Comment: @MathLover I didn't look closely at his answer but remember arcsin and arccos add up to $\pi/2$ (a constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of the sign in your approach. The result you derived is valid only for $x>0$. The full result valid for all domain is, instead

$$\int \frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)\sqrt {1+x^4}} dx
=-\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{\sqrt 2} \arctan \frac{\sqrt { x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}}{\sqrt 2} 
=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \arctan \frac{ \sqrt { x^4 +1}}{{\sqrt 2}x}
$$

which, as expected, differs from the given answer by a constant, i.e.

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \arctan \frac{ \sqrt { x^4 +1}}{{\sqrt 2}x}- \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} \arcsin \frac{\sqrt {2}x}{x^2+1}=-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}$$

Note

$$-\int \frac{dt}{t\sqrt {t^2-2}}
= \int \frac{d(\frac1t)}{\sqrt {1-\frac2{t^2}}}= \frac1{\sqrt2}\arcsin\frac{\sqrt2}t= \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} \arcsin \frac{\sqrt {2}x}{x^2+1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{-\int{\dd t \over
t\root{t^{2} - 2}}}\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{Set}\,\,\, t\ =\ \root{2}\sec\pars{\theta}~}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int{\root{2}\sec\pars{\theta}\tan\pars{\theta} \over \root{2}\sec\pars{\theta}
\bracks{\root{2}\tan\pars{\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\root{2} \over 2}\int\dd\theta =
-\,{\root{2} \over 2}\,\theta + \mbox{a constant}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\root{2} \over 2}\,
\arccos\pars{\root{2} \over t} + \mbox{a constant}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-\,{\root{2} \over 2}
\arccos\pars{\root{2}\,{x \over x^{2} + 1}} + \mbox{a constant}}
\\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Why does my answer give the wrong results?